2-3/8 galvanized steel fence post over 1-5/8 in
I want to replace a 4 ft tall chainlink fence with 6 or 8 ft tall cedar picket fence. The existing fence posts a 1-5/8 in., 16 gauge (I think), set in a concrete beam about 70 ft long. Rather than try to remove/replace the existing fence posts, I want to put a 2-3/8 in 6 ft post over the existing ones.
I did this on one portion of the fence already, where there is a cinder block wall immediately behind it, so I wasn't worried about structural integrity; it was mostly just cosmetic. For those posts, I just jammed some scrap shims into the gap between the existing pole and the new pole so the new ones wouldn't move around too much. This other section, however, needs to be solid and stand up to wind, etc, like a normal, free-standing plank fence.
The question is: what is a good way to secure the 2-3/8 post over the existing 1-5/8 post, or otherwise extend the height of the 4ft posts to accommodate, in a structurally sound way, a 6 ft tall plank fence?
Ideas I had:

extension on top of the existing post; There exist 1-5/8 in, 2ft extensions, however the only ones I could find are designed for smaller-gauged posts, and I don't think they will fit. Also I am not sure how strong that would be for a 6ft, much less 8ft fence.
slide 2-3/8 posts over, and secure them with 2 carriage bolts drilled through each fence post. This seems like it would probably be pretty sturdy, but kind of a pain to drill through the 4 layers of steel twice on each of 10 posts...
slide 2-3/8 in posts over, and fill the gap between the inner 1-5/8 in post and the outer 2-3/8 in post with concrete, by covering the inner hole of the smaller pole and pouring concrete through the top of the larger pole. This seems maybe more solid, but more irreversible, and maybe not actually feasible.

Any other idea, or experience with a similar approach? And, should I really only consider 6 ft tall fence, or would some answer to the first question be suitable to an 8 ft fence?

Before you make an 8 foot fence, check height limits with your municipality. Some don't allow fences taller than 6 ft except on commercially zoned properties.

All the bending strength will come from the 1 5/8 posts.  Make sure they are strong enough to not bend.  The bigger posts will be the same as cheater bars, bigger pipes that fit over something to bend or break them.
